# How to find $x$ value such that $x^5\equiv 99 \pmod{21}$ using congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I know congruences somewhat, however this problem is troubling me a lot. Please help me.

If $17^5\equiv 5 \pmod {21}$, then at what value of x, $x^5\equiv 99 \pmod{21}$?

High regards,
ZION

Comment: Solving $x^5\equiv 99\pmod{21}$ is simple, we want a number $x$ divisible by $3$ such that $x^5\equiv 1\pmod{7}$. This is $15$ but I don't see the connection with $17^5$.  Usual trap, once one sees a way to do something it is hard to change point of view.

Comment: @AndréNicolas! solve x^5 = 99 (mod 21)? so that I will think what to do...

Comment: @AndréNicolas! Sir forgot about 17^5 and so on. Please find x such that x^5 = 99 (mod 21)?

Comment: I did in the comment above, said $15$ explicitly. For solving $x^5\equiv 99\equiv 1\pmod{7}$ is very easy.

Comment: @AndréNicolas! what is the x value? I know that 99 = 1 (mod 7)

Comment: @AndréNicolas! Sir...let me learn from you. Please solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is to find $x$ where $x^a \equiv b \pmod N$ for composite $N$.

The way to do this is to write the problem as a *polynomial factorization* problem modulo $N$. In other words, we write $x^a - b \equiv 0 \pmod{N}$.

Now for any polynomial factorization problem we first decompose $N$ into its prime factors, and solve each congruence separately:
$$21 = 3 \cdot 7$$

So we have to solve these congruences:
$$x^5 - 99 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$$
$$x^5 - 99 \equiv 0 \pmod 7$$

In general, we would factor each polynomial over the modulus, then we would see the roots $x$ (just like when you solve a quadratic equation by factoring it). However, your particular problem is so easy we actually don't have to factor anything. Reduce $99$ by each modulus and you'll see this. In other words, $99\equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ and $99\equiv 1 \pmod{7}$. So now we have:

$$x^5 - 0 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$$
$$x^5 - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 7$$

How do we solve the first congruence? Well, what number to the 5th power equals 0? That's easy: Zero!

How do we solve the second congruence? Well, what number to the 5th power equals 1? That's also easy: 1.

If the constants were anything else, we might have to use complicated polynomial factoring algorithms like [Berlekamp's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%27s_algorithm) or the [Cantor–Zassenhaus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_algorithm) algorithm, which are out of my league.

Now that we have our $x$'s for each factor of $N$, we use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to solve $x$ for these congruences:
$$x \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$$
$$x \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$$

Since the solution for $x$ will apply modulo both prime factors of $N$, it will therefore apply modulo $N$, and we have our solution.

You can read about the Chinese Remainder Theorem [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem). And there is a [nice calculator to solve it here](http://davidwees.com/chineseremaindertheorem/). Just type in the last two equations (using an equals sign and no parentheses), and you'll have the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To solve $x^5\equiv 99\pmod{21}$ is equivalent to solving the system $x^5\equiv 1\pmod{7}$, $x^5\equiv 0\pmod{3}$.

The solution to $x^5\equiv 0\pmod{3}$ is obvious: $x\equiv 0\pmod{3}$.

It is clear that $x\equiv 1\pmod{7}$ is a solution of $x^5\equiv 1\pmod{7}$. There are in fact no other solutions.

Finally, we want to solve the system of two linear congruences,
$$x\equiv 1\pmod{7},\quad x\equiv 0\pmod{3}.$$
 One could use the machinery of the Chinese Remainder Theorem. But that would be overkill here. We want $x$ to be congruent to $1$ modulo $7$ and to be divisible by $3$. The answer is $x\equiv 15\pmod{21}$.

**Remark:** I do not see any useful connection between the above solution and the fact that $17^5\equiv 5\pmod{21}$.